# Bridging two different Jabber MUC's

Tags: bridge, chat, jabber, xmpp

I am a webmaster of a gaming clan. We have a Jabber powered MUC inside the game, and we have another MUC that came with our website. I was wondering if there is anyway to link them so we could have a webchat for example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Jabber Transports could be a way to go for you, depending on the technique your web chat uses...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP#Connecting_to_other_protocols
http://spectrum.im